# Interview challenge: Find the different elements in two arrays

Tags: algorithm

> - Stage 1: Given two arrays, say A[] and B[], how could you find out if elements of B is in A?
> - Stage 2: What about the size of A[] is 10000000000000... and B[] is much smaller than this?
> - Stage 3: What about the size of B[] is also 10000000000.....?

My answer is as follows:

- Stage 1:

  1. double for loop - O(N^2);
  2. sort A[], then binary search - O(NlgN)
- Stage 2:
  using bit set, since the integer is 32bits....
- Stage 3: ..

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: Now for the all-important question: can you assume anything about the data types of elements of A and B, other than that they are of the same type? Monumentally important question. Strings or integers, perhaps?

Comment: the question is poorly specified - what are the elements of the arrays?  integers? strings?  if integers, are they within a certain range?  Are we trying to see if all the elements in B are in A, or are we trying to see if any of the elements of B are in A?  Or are we trying to find a list of all the elements in B that are in A?  What are the limits on memory?  IE would an array of size 1000000000000... fit in memory?  On disk?  Are the arrays sorted?  Do we have to do the serach in place or can we build extra data structures? etc etc.

Comment: Read up on Relational Database Joins. That is essentially the same group of algorithms, such as sorted join and hash join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hash all elements in `A` [iterate the array and insert the elements into a hash-set], then iterate B, and check for each element if it is in `B` or not. you can get average run time of `O(|A|+|B|)`.

You cannot get sub-linear complexity, so this solution is **optimal for average case analyzis**, however, since hashing is **not** `O(1)` *worst case*, you might get bad worst-case performance.

**EDIT:**

If you don't have enough space to store a hash set of elements in B, you might want to concider a probabilistic solution using [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). The problem: there might be some false positives [but never false negative]. Accuracy of being correct increases as you allocate more space for the bloom filter.

The other solution is as you said, sort, which will be `O(nlogn)` time, and then use binary search for all elements in B on the sorted array.

For 3rd stage, you get same complexity: `O(nlogn)` with the same solution, it will take approximately double time then stage 2, but still `O(nlogn)`

**EDIT2:**

Note that instead of using a regular hash, sometimes you can use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) [depands on your elements type], for example: for ints, store the number as it was a string, each digit will be like a character. with this solution, you get `O(|B|*num_digits+|A|*num_digits)` solution, where `num_digits` is the number of digits in your numbers [if they are ints]. Assuming `num_digits` is bounded with a finite size, you get `O(|A|+|B|)` **worst case**.

Comment: Yes. Hash is OK for stage1. What about stage2? The Hash Table will become too large....

Comment: @deepsky: For large data, you might want to use [Bloom Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), which can get you correct answer in high probability [you might get false positives, but never false negatives]. The probability of being correct increases as you allocate more space for your bloom filter.

Answer (score 2):

**Stage 1:** make a hash set from `A` and iterate over `B`, checking if current element `B[i]` exists in `A` (same way that @amit proposed earlier). Complexity (averaged) - O(length(A) + length(B)).

**Stage 2:** make a hash set **from `B`**, then iterate over `A` and if current element exists in `B`, **remove it from `B`**. If after iterating `B` has at least 1 element, then not all `B`'s element exist in `A`; otherwise `A` is complete superset of `B`. Complexity (averaged) - O(length(A) + length(B)).

**Stage 3:** sort both arrays in-place and iterate, searching for same numbers on current positions `i` and `j` for `A[i]` and `B[j]` (the idea must be obvious). Complexity - O(n*log n), where n = length(A).

Comment: What sort algorithm are you going to use to sort both large arrays in place? I can't think of any in-place guaranteed O(n lg n) sorts.

Comment: Heapsort? Also, you can do merge-sort in O(1) space, but the implementation is ugly.

Comment: Heapsort could do it. The in place merge sort has O(n (lg n)^2) time, says wikipedia.

Comment: @jb.: if they are _arrays_ they are already in the memory, so quick sort will be ok. If they are on the disk, they are files and completely different algorithm is needed. Note, that quick sort is not guaranteed to be O(n*log n), but none of general purpose algorithms that I know are.